# How do you set the axes parameter in TensorFlow moments for batch normalization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, batch-normalization

I am planning on implementing a batch normalization function similar to [this blog](https://medium.com/@ntoyonaga/tensorflow-dataset-api-implementation-of-preprocessing-batch-normalization-174d6e0f9905) (or just using [`tf.nn.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization)) using [`tf.nn.moments`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/moments) to compute mean and variance, but I wish to do it for temporal data, both of vector and image type. I am generally having a little trouble understanding how to set the `axes` argument correctly in `tf.nn.moments`.

My input data for vector sequences has shape `(batch, timesteps, channels)`, and my input data for image sequences has shape `(batch, timesteps, height, width, 3)` (note they are RGB images). In both cases I want the normalization to happen across the entire batch **and** across timesteps, meaning I am **not** trying to maintain separate mean/variance for different timesteps.

How to correctly set `axes` for different data types (e.g. image, vector) and for temporal/non-temporal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to think of it is - axes passed into `axes` will be *collapsed*, and statistics will be computed by *slicing over* the `axes`. Example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform((8, 10, 4))

print(x, '\n')
print(tf.nn.moments(x, axes=[0]), '\n')
print(tf.nn.moments(x, axes=[0, 1]))
```

```py
Tensor("random_uniform:0", shape=(8, 10, 4), dtype=float32)

(<tf.Tensor 'moments/Squeeze:0'   shape=(10, 4) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'moments/Squeeze_1:0' shape=(10, 4) dtype=float32>)

(<tf.Tensor 'moments_1/Squeeze:0'   shape=(4,) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'moments_1/Squeeze_1:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32>)
```

From source, [`math_ops.reduce_mean`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1221) is used to compute both `mean` and `variance`, which operates as, in pseudocode:

```py
# axes = [0]
mean = (x[0, :, :] + x[1, :, :] + ... + x[7, :, :]) / 8
mean.shape == (10, 4)  # each slice's shape is (10, 4), so sum's shape is also (10, 4)

# axes = [0, 1]
mean = (x[0, 0,  :] + x[1, 0,  :] + ... + x[7, 0,  :] +
        x[0, 1,  :] + x[1, 1,  :] + ... + x[7, 1,  :] +
        ... +
        x[0, 10, :] + x[1, 10, :] + ... + x[7, 10, :]) / (8 * 10)
mean.shape == (4, ) # each slice's shape is (4, ), so sum's shape is also (4, )
```

---

In other words, `axes=[0]` will compute `(timesteps, channels)` statistics with respect to `samples` - i.e. iterate over `samples`, compute mean & variance of `(timesteps, channels)` slices. Thus, for

> normalization to happen across the entire batch and across timesteps, meaning I am **not** trying to maintain separate mean/variance for different timesteps

you just need to collapse the `timesteps` dimension (along `samples`), and compute statistics by iterating over both `samples` and `timesteps`:

```py
axes = [0, 1]
```

Same story for images, except as you have two non-channel/sample dimensions, you'd do `axes = [0, 1, 2]` (to collapse `samples, height, width`).

---

**Pseudocode demo**: see mean computation in action

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

x = tf.constant(np.random.randn(8, 10, 4))
result1 = tf.add(x[0], tf.add(x[1], tf.add(x[2], tf.add(x[3], tf.add(x[4], 
                       tf.add(x[5], tf.add(x[6], x[7]))))))) / 8
result2 = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=0)
print(K.eval(result1 - result2))
```

```py
# small differences per numeric imprecision
[[ 2.77555756e-17  0.00000000e+00 -5.55111512e-17 -1.38777878e-17]
 [-2.77555756e-17  2.77555756e-17  0.00000000e+00 -1.38777878e-17]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -5.55111512e-17  0.00000000e+00 -2.77555756e-17]
 [-1.11022302e-16  2.08166817e-17  2.22044605e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [-5.55111512e-17  2.77555756e-17 -1.11022302e-16  5.55111512e-17]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -2.77555756e-17]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -5.55111512e-17]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -3.46944695e-17 -2.77555756e-17  1.11022302e-16]
 [-5.55111512e-17  5.55111512e-17  0.00000000e+00  1.11022302e-16]]
```

Comment: Regarding your last point about images, you mean using `axes=[0,1,2]` for the non-temporal case right?. If I am processing image sequences, then it would be `axes=[0,1,2,3]` so that it would collapse `samples, timesteps, height, width`?

Comment: @adamconkey Correct